# test if one numpy array is between arrays a and b

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

say I have three numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([8,2,10,10])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8])
c = np.array([9,10,11,12])
```

I would like to do an element-wise test if a is between b and c. And if so, return something like:

```
["Pass","Fail","Pass","Pass"]
```

Comment: corrected.  3 numpy arrays, want to do an element-wise comparison

Answer (score 2):

Via Pandas:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[a,b,c]).T
df.columns=['a','b','c']
```

Finally:

```
result=df['a'].between(df['b'],df['c']).apply(lambda x:'Pass' if x else 'Fail').values
```

Now If you print result you will get your desired output:

```
array(['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Pass'], dtype=object)
```

---

AS Noted in comment by @user2357112 supports Monica:

pandas.Series.between defaults to an inclusive "betweenness" check, so 2 is considered to be between 2 and 3. If you want an exclusive check, you can pass `inclusive=False`

i.e:

```
result=df['a'].between(df['b'],df['c'],inclusive=False).apply(lambda x:'Pass' if x else 'Fail').values
```

**Note:** It is not much efficient(speedwise) as compared to numpy's `where()` method for large/huge data but it will do the work

Comment: nice alternative example. didn't know about between

Comment: Note that `pandas.Series.between` defaults to an inclusive "betweenness" check, so 2 is considered to be between 2 and 3. If you want an exclusive check, you can pass `inclusive=False` to `between`.

Comment: Also, the arguments are treated as "left boundary" and "right boundary", not "one boundary" and "other boundary", so 2 is considered between 1 and 3, but not between 3 and 1.